# Handle a 401 error in Volley's onErrorResponse listener

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley's `JsonObjectRequest` to fetch JSON data from a web server. Basically my code looks like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest("https://www.example.com", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        ...
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == 401) {
            // Show toast message saying "Access unauthorized"
        } else {
            // show toast message saying "Could not fetch"
        }
    }
});
```

If the request fails with a 401 error, the "Access unauthorized" toast message is shown as expected. However, if the request fails for some reason such as no internet, the app crashes and throws a `NullPointerException` because `networkResponse` does not exist in `error`.

How do I properly handle both causes of failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this in either of this below ways,

1. Handle the lost internet signal in your app and navigate to a different page (search for how to handle no internet, lot of articles available)
2. Surround JsonObjectRequest call in try catch and handle the exception on your own

Comment: Ok, I will go with the second option. Thank you.